# ROS Answers SE migration: nxt fuerte

Tags: nxt, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings everyone

I've just installed fuerte and i finished all the beginner tutorials,  and i would like to start with my nxt robot and an arduino. The thing is that i cant find instructions to install it fort fuerte, Am i able to install it using the instruction for electric? if not how do I install it? in advance thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35746/nxt-fuerte/) by [Mr.EEPBppt](https://answers.ros.org/users/2547/mr.eepbppt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, there is not a nxtall package for fuerte yet. Have you considered installing electric on your system? There are not a lot of libraries for the arduino and nxt, and I think the best support for those systems would be in electric (the nxt recommends you install diamondback, but the arduino rosserial system works better [from my experiences] in electric).

Hope this helps!
-Hunter A.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0